# Carrierwave & sideliq & file size validator. Error: already initialized constant FileSizeValidator

Tags: carrierwave, sidekiq

I'm using carrierwave and file_size_validator
and I'm using sidekiq.
When I run "bundle exec sidekiq " in console
I see this errors

```
/lib/file_size_validator.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant FileSizeValidator::MESSAGES
lib/file_size_validator.rb:5: warning: previous definition of MESSAGES was here
lib/file_size_validator.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant FileSizeValidator::CHECKS
lib/file_size_validator.rb:6: warning: previous definition of CHECKS was here
lib/file_size_validator.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant FileSizeValidator::DEFAULT_TOKENIZER
lib/file_size_validator.rb:8: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_TOKENIZER was here
lib/file_size_validator.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant FileSizeValidator::RESERVED_OPTIONS
/lib/file_size_validator.rb:9: warning: previous definition of RESERVED_OPTIONS was here
```

Answer (score 2):

problem solved 
I remove string 
    require 'file_size_validator'
from models 
because in my application.rb file

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```